# Does Postgres Plus Advanced Server (PPAS) 9.5 support altering (dropping/adding) attributes to composite object types?

Tags: composite-types, postgres-plus

According to my reading of the PostgreSQL documentation on [`ALTER TYPE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertype.html) I should be able to do the following:

```
CREATE TYPE compfoo AS OBJECT (f1 int, f2 text);
CREATE TYPE compbar AS OBJECT (f1 int, f2 compfoo);
ALTER TYPE compbar DROP ATTRIBUTE f2;
ALTER TYPE compbar ADD ATTRIBUTE f2 varying(1000);
ALTER TYPE compbar ADD ATTRIBUTE f3 compfoo;
```

However, when I try it, I get the following error:

`ERROR:  ALTER TYPE ADD/DROP COLUMN statement not supported for object types`

What am I missing here? Is there a server configuration that will allow me to do this? Is it because the type in question is a composite `OBJECT` type, as opposed to a composite of 'basic' types?

*UPDATE 2015-02-10*
I've updated the title, and the samples to more closely resemble the problem at hand. In short, within Postgres Plus Advanced Server, there's additional syntax for creating types, in the form `CREATE TYPE foo AS OBJECT` <--- that syntax is the root of the issue. You cannot alter attributes when the composite type was created `AS OBJECT`.

Comment: Looks like a typing error! You are creating `combbar` (in line 2) and then expecting `compbar` to exist (in line 3), which obviously wouldn't!

Comment: It's a typo... I've fixed it.

Comment: I rolled the question back to its previous version. Altering the question to hide the original errors makes the answers look silly instead of the question, IMHO.

Comment: @wildplasser it was NOT hiding the original error - it was updating for clarity. The original error was something else entirely. Seriously, either close the question with the typo flag so I can resubmit with better typing skills, or let me fix it...

Comment: What is the protocol if I have the answer (as in my update)? Just leave it as part of the question, or submit my own answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (f1 int, f2 text);
CREATE TYPE combbar AS (f1 int, f2 compfoo);
ALTER TYPE compbar DROP ATTRIBUTE f2;
---------------^ maybe you should write combbar?
```

To make it clear you are defining a type named "combbar" and then you try to alter a type with the name "compbar".

**UPDATE**

Besides that typo, the SQL seems to run [fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/34d54/2).